How to create and search through a repository using Copyleaks Python SDK?
I am creating a program in Python which compares 2 or more files for similarity. A great tool I've found is Copyleaks, which is not a usual diffchecker, but also looks at synonyms and paraphrasing.
How can I create a repository and search it using Copyleaks Python SDK? Or is there a better method to achieve my goal?
I have found this usage example on github which uses SearchRepository() method, but it has no declaration.
repo = SearchRepository()
repo.set_include_my_submissions(True)
repo.set_include_others_submissions(True)
repo.set_id("ID_FETCHED_DASHBOARD")
scan_properties.set_scanning(Scanning().set_repositories(repo))


Creating a new Copyleaks Repository can be done through the admin dashboard.
After creating the repository you will be able to copy the RepositoryID. Then using the example you shared above will use this repository in the scan.

Thanks. From the python side, how can I use SearchRepository() class? How do I import it?

As the previous answer indicated, creating a new Copyleaks Repository can be done through the admin dashboard. You can also access the same flow from the webapp, by clicking on "Repositories" from the left hand menu. Pricing is based on repository size, and can be adjusted as needed.
Please note, you may be required to create a Copyleaks Organization during the process of creating a repository. It will not cost you anything to set up a Copyleaks Organization.

Thanks. From the python side, how can I use SearchRepository() class? How do I import it?

You can import by adding these two lines of text:
from copyleaks.models.submit.properties.repository import SearchRepository
from copyleaks.models.submit.properties.scanning import Scanning
